# I tried to input N times into a char type variable, and 'input' works only one time but 'output' works N times

Tags: c++, char, cin, cout

when I input 5 into `n` and input '12345' for `a`, `cin` works only one time but `cout` works 5 times.
How could it be?

```cpp
int main(){
   int n;
   cin >> n;
   char a;

   for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
      cin >> a;
      cout << a << ' ';
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific about the problem. What do you mean with "works only once"? The easiest way to do so is to show us expected and actual output. Because I can't actually reproduce your problem: with input "5 12345" output is "1 2 3 4 5" - as expected, I guess.

Comment: With `12345` you write 5 characters into the stream and `cin` can read 5 times.

Comment: Try to change `char a` to `int a` or `std::string a`.

Comment: `char a;` a `char` is a single character not a string. It can't possibly hold "12345"

Comment: Unless you tell us what you actually expected to happen it's impossible to find a definitve answer.

Answer (score 2):

`cin` works also 5 times. `char` means a character. In the sequence '12345' you have 5 characters. When you enter this you enter 5 values. So, first time `cin` reads value 1, after it reads value '2', after 3 and so on.. So that, you see the output 1 2 3 4 5